# How to redirect to another page if prop is not defined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, destructuring

I have a component that receives props and displays the received props. So I decided to load this page url without receiving a prop and I get this error:

```
   TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'myImage' of '(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
```

So I tried to redirect the page if the props is not received (if it is undefined) with the following lines of code:

```
    componentDidMount(){
        if(this.props.location.myInfo === undefined){
            this.props.history.push('/');
            return;
        }
        this.setState({ name: this.props.location.myInfo });
    }
   render(){
      const { myImage, myName, myJobType, myPrice } = this.props.location.myInfo ? this.props.location.myInfo : this.props.history.push('/');
      return(
         <div>
            ...
         </div>
      )
   }
```

But none of these works. Been on it for hours trying different methods but none is working, how can I get if fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more than one line to do this:

1. Destructure this.props.location.myInfo and add optional value {}.
2. Call this.props.history.push if this.props.location.myInfo is undefined.

```js
render(){
      const { myImage, myName, myJobType, myPrice } = this.props.location.myInfo || {};
      if(!this.props.location.myInfo) {
          this.props.history.push('/')
      }
      return(
         <div>
            //...
         </div>
      )
   }
```

or

```js
componentDidMount() {
  if(!this.props.location.myInfo) {
     this.props.history.push('/')
  }
}

render(){
  const { myImage, myName, myJobType, myPrice } = this.props.location.myInfo || {};   
  return
  (
     <div>
        //...
     </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I later got it fixed by wrapping the inside of my ```<React.Fragment>``` with ```{ this.props.location.hotelInfo !== undefined && <div>...</div>``` and it worked. I'm gonna try both of your options too and come back to rate accordingly. Thanks